# Why does my Task Manager say one core but Device Manager shows 8?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, cpu-cores

On my PC it shows I have 8 cores in Device Manager, but when I go to task manager it shows only 1 logical processor. Can someone fix this for me?

Under the processors tab in Device Manager 8 cores show up showing what I have, then when I open up task manager only one core and 1 logical processor shows up and I cannot change it in the msconfig. I had it at 8 before now I can’t go higher than 1.

Task Manager only shows one logical processor when it used to show 8

[image: Task Manager]

Here's the screenshot of the Device Manager.

[image: Device Manager]

IDK what I did or what happened, but I went from an average of 700 fps to 15

Comment: What does Task Manager show in Logical Processors (right lower side of the CPU Window.  Task Manager says I have one CPU but 4 logical processors which is correct. So I think what you see is normal. Windows 10 V1909 up to date.

Comment: Screenshots would be useful to see where your problems are.

Comment: @user1147782 you must [edit] your own question to add more information instead of adding them to my answer

Comment: @phuclv if you go to my profile I created a new question witht he same things but it has the pictures

Comment: @user1147782 - **Edit** this question.  Do not submit a comment or another question with a screenshot from the **BOOT Advanced Options** from `msconfig`.

Answer (score 4):

First, it's probably not actually not 8 cores but 4 cores 8 threads, unless you're using some CPUs without Hyperthreading. You can see the number of cores and threads in the performance tab of Task Manager. The CPU usage in that tab is also a **combined** value for all the CPUs by default. Just right click > Change graph to > Logical processors

---

## Update:

After you updated the question with images, it's clear that you've accidentally limit the number of CPUs in the configuration. Just run `msconfig` and remove the limit. See [Ramhound's answer for more details](https://superuser.com/a/1532123/241386)

---

[image: 1 core]

[image: 8 core]

Comment: The [i7-9700F](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/193738/intel-core-i7-9700f-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-70-ghz.html) is an 8 core Intel processor that does NOT support Hyperthreading.  Additionally, and this is the reason I reversed my upvote, the user's screenshot of task manager is literally reporting the utilization of a single processor with 1 core with 1 thread.  **This isn't the case of `overall utilization` otherwise Task Manager would report those 8 cores in and combine them in a single graph.**

Comment: yes I know, the OP just uploaded the screenshots recently

Answer (score 2):

> On my PC it shows I have 8 cores in Device Manager, but when I go to task manager it shows only 1 logical processor. Can someone fix this for me?

You have inadvertently disabled your other cores on your processor.

[image]

You can enable all your cores by launching `MSConfig` and selecting "Advanced options...`and unselecting the`Number of Processors`checkbox within the`BOOT Advanced Option` window.

[image]

> Under the processor's tab in Device Manager 8 cores show up showing what I have, then when I open up task manager only one core and 1 logical processor shows up and I cannot change it in the MSConfig. I had it at 8 before now I can’t go higher than 1.

Based on the fact Task Manager is reporting 1 processor with a single core, it's unlikely you have also inadvertently enabled "Overall utilization" within the Performance tab, even if you had enabled "Overall utilization" **Task Manager would report a single processor with 8 cores instead of 1 core.**

> [image]